# Different ways of specify the same formula in regression get different results

Tags: r

Recently, I came across a very wired problem and I cannot solve it even by using Chatgpt4. Initially, I want to make a loop to do repeated work of regression because i have different combinations of independent variables and dependent variables. Here is my coding and demo dataset:

```
###create a dataset with repeated measurement, var d stands for ID, Cal is dependent variable, a,b,c are independent variables
n_participants <- 50
n_measurements <- 3
a <- rnorm(n_participants*n_measurements, mean = 10, sd = 2)
b <- rnorm(n_participants*n_measurements, mean = 5, sd = 1)
c <- rnorm(n_participants*n_measurements, mean = 20, sd = 3)
d <- rep(1:n_participants, each = n_measurements)
Cal <- rbinom(n_participants*n_measurements, size = 1, prob = 0.5)

###add NA to dataset
missing_prop <- 0.2
missing_index <- sample(length(a), size = ceiling(length(a)*missing_prop))
a[missing_index] <- NA
b[missing_index] <- NA
c[missing_index] <- NA
Cal[missing_index] <- NA
data <- data.frame(Cal, a, b, c, d)

###mice imputed
imputed_data <- mice(data, m = 5, maxit = 50, seed = 123)
###check whether the data were imputed completely
complete_data <- complete(imputed_data)
summary(complete_data)

###regression by imputed data, thus with() is need
###solution 1
rg1 <- with(imputed_data, geeglm(Cal ~ a, family = binomial, id = d, corstr = "independence"))
summary(rg1)
###solution 2
var <- "a"
formula <- as.formula(paste0("Cal ~ ", var))
rg2 <- with(imputed_data, geeglm(formula, family = binomial, id = d, corstr = "independence"))
summary(rg2)
```

As shown in solution 2, I first specify the formula by as.formula. I double checked the formula is the same as "Cal ~ a", in other word the same as in solution 1 directly type the formula in the regression model. But the coefficients from solution2 is different from solution1.
What is happening when I use as.formula rather than directly type the formula into the regression model.

Maybe the way I wrap the regression to a loop is not appropriate. Could any expert share some experience with wrapping a regression into a loop? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's the place where you call `as.formula()`. It seems to record the environnment in which it is called, and with your solution 2 I get the results on the original dataset `data`.

I'm not that experienced with these and don't know how to specify a proper environnment, but you can call `as.formula()` inside the `with()` function and it seems to work with me.

```
    ###solution 1
    rg1 <- with(imputed_data, geeglm(Cal ~ a, family = binomial, id = d, corstr = "independence"))
    summary(rg1)
    # A tibble: 10 x 6
       term        estimate std.error statistic p.value  nobs
       <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <int>
     1 (Intercept) -0.340      0.880   0.150      0.699   150
     2 a            0.0629     0.0862  0.533      0.465   150
     3 (Intercept) -0.253      0.802   0.0995     0.752   150
     4 a            0.0568     0.0779  0.531      0.466   150
     5 (Intercept)  0.512      0.834   0.376      0.540   150
     6 a           -0.0423     0.0810  0.272      0.602   150
     7 (Intercept)  0.0251     0.796   0.000992   0.975   150
     8 a            0.0265     0.0783  0.115      0.735   150
     9 (Intercept)  0.297      0.912   0.106      0.745   150
    10 a           -0.00538    0.0873  0.00380    0.951   150

    

    ###solution 2
    var <- "a"
    formula <- as.formula(paste0("Cal ~ ", var))
    rg2 <- with(imputed_data, geeglm(formula, family = binomial, id = d, corstr = "independence"))
    summary(rg2)
    # A tibble: 10 x 6
       term        estimate std.error statistic p.value  nobs
       <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <int>
     1 (Intercept)   0.0688    0.879    0.00614   0.938   120
     2 a             0.0230    0.0859   0.0715    0.789   120
     3 (Intercept)   0.0688    0.879    0.00614   0.938   120
     4 a             0.0230    0.0859   0.0715    0.789   120
     5 (Intercept)   0.0688    0.879    0.00614   0.938   120
     6 a             0.0230    0.0859   0.0715    0.789   120
     7 (Intercept)   0.0688    0.879    0.00614   0.938   120
     8 a             0.0230    0.0859   0.0715    0.789   120
     9 (Intercept)   0.0688    0.879    0.00614   0.938   120
    10 a             0.0230    0.0859   0.0715    0.789   120
     
    # Produces the same
    summary(geeglm(Cal ~ a, data = data, family = binomial, id = d, corstr = "independence"))
            
            Call:
            geeglm(formula = Cal ~ a, family = binomial, data = data, id = d, 
                corstr = "independence")
            
             Coefficients:
                        Estimate Std.err  Wald Pr(>|W|)
            (Intercept)  0.06884 0.87884 0.006    0.938
            a            0.02296 0.08586 0.071    0.789
            
            Correlation structure = independence 
            Estimated Scale Parameters:
            
                        Estimate Std.err
            (Intercept)        1 0.03166
            Number of clusters:   50  Maximum cluster size: 3
    
    # Solution 3 (same results as solution 1)
    formula <- paste0("Cal ~ ", var)
    rg3 <- with(imputed_data, geeglm(as.formula(formula), family = binomial, id = d, corstr = "independence"))
    summary(rg3)
        # A tibble: 10 x 6
           term        estimate std.error statistic p.value  nobs
       <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <int>
     1 (Intercept) -0.340      0.880   0.150      0.699   150
     2 a            0.0629     0.0862  0.533      0.465   150
     3 (Intercept) -0.253      0.802   0.0995     0.752   150
     4 a            0.0568     0.0779  0.531      0.466   150
     5 (Intercept)  0.512      0.834   0.376      0.540   150
     6 a           -0.0423     0.0810  0.272      0.602   150
     7 (Intercept)  0.0251     0.796   0.000992   0.975   150
     8 a            0.0265     0.0783  0.115      0.735   150
     9 (Intercept)  0.297      0.912   0.106      0.745   150
    10 a           -0.00538    0.0873  0.00380    0.951   150
```

My take is that when you call `as.formula` in global environnment it "remembers" that it is called here and searches for a data.frame in that environnment with variables Cal and a. Moving it in with, the environnment isn't the global one anymore and it uses the data.frame in the mice object.
I hope this is not too clumpsy and that it helped. Maybe someone with further knowledge will explain that quirk so that we both understand it!

Comment: Thanks ! this works for me too. Your answer is very clear! Highly appreciate your prompt answer!